# QMessageBox on top of QDialog

Tags: python, qt, qmessagebox

I'm reimplementing the accept method of a qdialog so that when the ok button is clicked,  a `QMessageBox` will show up on top of the qdialog. The `QDialog` is a modal window on top of a main window. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Found the solution after some tinkering. The trick is to call the QMessagebox without a parent.

Comment: you should add your comment as an answer and accept it so that people can see that your question no longer needs an answer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer